Factoriadic Fraction Addition
Objective
Given two rational numbers represented in fractional factoriadic as defined below, add them, and output the result in fractional factoriadic.
Fractional factoriadic
Fractional factoriadic is a numeral system that represents every rational number using \$1/2\$'s place, \$1/6\$'s place, \$1/{24}\$'s place and so on (in general, \$1/{n!}\$'s place for each integer \$n \geq 2\$), with these digits of choice:

The digit at \$1/2\$'s place may be any integer.
The digit at \$1/6\$'s place may be \$0\$, \$1\$ or \$2\$.
The digit at \$1/{24}\$'s place may be \$0\$, \$1\$, \$2\$, or \$3\$.
The digit at \$1/{120}\$'s place may be \$0\$, \$1\$, \$2\$, \$3\$, or \$4\$.
Ad infinitum. In general, for every integer \$n \geq 3\$, the digit at \$1/{n!}\$'s place may be from \$0\$ to \$n-1\$ inclusive.

Mathematical remarks
Fractional factoriadic identifies \$\mathbb{Q}\$ as the direct limit of the following inclusion sequence in the category of abelian groups:
$$
\langle 1/2 \rangle \to \langle 1/6 \rangle \to \langle 1/{24} \rangle \to \langle 1/{120} \rangle \to \langle 1/{720} \rangle \to \cdots 
$$
I/O format
It is assumed that the inputted fractions are MSD-first and have no trailing zeros. This applies to the output also.
Examples
Fraction = intermediate representation = fractional factoriadic

0 = 0/2 = []
1 = 2/2 = [2]
2 = 4/2 = [4]
3/2 = 3/2 = [3]
-1/2 = -1/2 = [-1]
1/3 = 2/6 = [0, 2]
1/4 = 1/6 + 2/24 = [0, 1, 2]
2/3 = 1/2 + 1/6 = [1, 1]
3/4 = 1/2 + 1/6 + 2/24 = [1, 1, 2]
1/5 = 1/6 + 4/120 = [0, 1, 0, 4]
-1/4 = -1/2 + 1/6 + 2/24 = [-1, 1, 2]
7/3 = 4/2 + 2/6 = [4, 2]

[] + [] = []
[] + [1] = [1]
[0, 2] + [-1] = [-1, 2]
[0, 2] + [0, 2] = [1, 1]
[0, 1, 2] + [0, 1, 2] = [1]


Is e.g. 1/8 supposed to be inexpressible in this system?

@att Should be [0,0,3]

the question text excludes 0 as a possible value of each place except the first

@att Sorry! Fixed by now.

I might suggest some larger test cases with unequal length. I had an almost-functional golf to Jonathan Allan's Jelly solution, but aside from erroring on the first test case, it also gets the third one wrong with the arguments reversed but not in the order given.

05AB1E (legacy), 16 bytes
ζOāvćsāÌ‰‚˜2ôO0Ü

First halve of the program is a port of @alephalpha's Nekomata's answer and the second halve is a port of @JonathanAllan's Jelly answer, so make sure to upvote both those answers as well!
Input as a pair of lists.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E so it won't need an additional leading 0, since invalid characters in a list when summing (a space in this case) are simply ignored in the legacy version.
ζ                # Zip/transpose the (implicit) input-pair; swapping rows/columns,
                 # using an implicit space " " as filler for unequal length rows
 O               # Sum each inner list, ignoring the spaces
  ā              # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
   v             # Pop and loop over those items (without using them),
                 # aka, `āv` is used to loop the length amount of times:
    ć            #  Extract head; push first item and remainder-list separately
     s           #  Swap so the remainder-list is at the top of the stack
      ā          #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
       Ì         #  Increase each by 2 to make the range [3,length+2]
        ‰        #  Divmod the remainder-list by this [3,length+2]-list
         ‚       #  Pair it with the extracted head
          ˜      #  Flatten this list
           2ô    #  Split it into pairs
             O   #  Sum each pair
              0Ü #  Trim any trailing 0s
                 # (after the loop, the resulting list is output implicitly)


Nekomata + -1, 18 bytes
+:#ᵑ{CU$x3+þç++;ž¿

Attempt This Online!
+:#ᵑ{CU$x3+þç++;ž¿
+                   Add two lists; pad with 0s
                    e.g. [0,2] [-1] -> [-1,2]
 :                  Duplicate
  #                 Length
   ᵑ{               Repeat the following function that many times:
     CU$                Split into the head and the rest
                        e.g. [0,2,4] -> [0] [2,4]
        x3+             Push [3,...,length+2]
                        e.g. [0] [2,4] -> [0] [2,4] [3,4]
           þ            Divmod; get the quotient and the remainder
                        e.g. [0] [2,4] [3,4] -> [0] [0,1] [2,0]
            ç           Prepend 0 to the remainder
                        e.g. [0] [0,1] [2,0] -> [0] [0,1] [0,2,0]
             ++         Add the three lists
                        e.g. [0] [0,1] [0,2,0] -> [0,3,0]
               ;ž¿      Remove some trailing 0s
                        e.g. [0,3,0] -> [0,3]

The last step ;ž¿ is nondeterministic, so we need to add the -1 flag to return only the first result, where all trailing 0s are removed.

R, 125 bytes
\(v,w,`^`=c,y=w^0,s=seq){a=(!s(x<-v^0)-(e=s(x+y)))*x+y*!s(y)-e
while(any(a-(a=a-(b=(a>e))*e-b+b[-1]^0)))1
a[s(l=max(e*!!a))]}

Attempt This Online!
How? - ungolfed version:
add_factoriadic=function(x,y){
    a<-c(x,y,0)&0                             # define a as long-enough vector of zeros 
    a[seq(!x)]=x                              # add x to appropriate elements
    a[seq(!y)]=a[seq(!y)]+y                   # add y to appropriate elements
    while({                                   # repeat while value of a changes:
        b=(a>seq(a))                          #   b = carry digits
        any(a-                                #   check whether a changes by
          (a=a+c(b[-1],0)                     #     add carry digits at position to left
              -b*(seq(a)+1)))                 #     and subtract carried values
    })1                                       #   (do nothing else)
    a[seq(length=max(seq(a)*!!a))]            # finally, output a without trailing zeros
}


Jelly, 17 bytes
+dṛ¦J‘$F+2/ƲÐLœr0

A dyadic Link that accepts factoriadic fractions as lists of integers on each side and yields their sum.
Try it online! Or see the test-suite.
How?
Repeated carrying...
+dṛ¦J‘$F+2/ƲÐLœr0 - Link: integer list, [a,b,c,...]; integer list, [x,y,z,...]
+                 - {A} add {B} (vectorises) -> S = [a+x, b+y, c+z, ...]
            ÐL    - repeat until the results are no longer unique:
           Ʋ      -   last four links as a monad:
      $           -     last two links as a monad:
    J             -       indices -> [1,2,...N]
     ‘            -       increment -> I = [2,3,...,N+1]
   ¦              -     sparse application (to {V in S} with {i in I})...
  ṛ               -     ...to indices: right argument = I
                           i.e. apply to all but the first element
 d                -     ...action: {V} divmod {i} -> [V//i, V%i]
       F          -     flatten -> [a+x, (b+y)//3, (b+y)%3, (c+z)//4, (c+z)%4, ...]
         2/       -     2-wise reduce by:
        +         -       addition -> [a+x+(b+y)//3, (b+y)%3+(c+z)//4, ...]
              œr0 - trim trailing zeros


Charcoal, 57 bytes
Ｆ⁻ＬηＬθ⊞θ⁰≔⁰ζＦ⮌Ｅηκ«≧⁺⁺§θι⊟ηζ§≔θι⎇ι﹪ζ⁺²ιζ≧÷⁺²ιζ»Ｗ∧θ¬↨θ⁰⊟θＩθ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｆ⁻ＬηＬθ⊞θ⁰

Extend the first input to the length of the second.
≔⁰ζ

Start with no carry.
Ｆ⮌Ｅηκ«

Enumerate the indices of the second array in reverse.
≧⁺⁺§θι⊟ηζ

Add the values in the two array elements to the carry.
§≔θι⎇ι﹪ζ⁺²ιζ

Update the output value, reducing modularly if necessary.
≧÷⁺²ιζ

Update the carry.
»Ｗ∧θ¬↨θ⁰⊟θ

Remove any trailing zeros.
Ｉθ

Output the final result.
Bonus 136-byte Retina 0.8.2 solution: Try it online! Does not work with negative numbers.

APL(Dyalog Unicode), 35 bytes SBCS
Assumes index origin 0.
{x↓⍨-⊥⍨0=x←(⊢⊤⊥∘m)(⊢+2××)⍳≢m←+⌿↑⍺⍵}

Try it on APLgolf!
Add the inputs element-wise, convert back and forth using mixed base 0 3 4 5 ..., drop trailing zeros.

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 71 bytes
If[#==0,{},{a=⌊++j#⌋,##&@@#0[j#-a]}]&@Tr[Tr[i=j=1;#/++i!&/@#]&/@#]&

Try it online!
Input [{numbers...}].
                                        Tr[i=  1;#/++i!&/@#]&/@#   from factoriadic
                                     Tr[                        ]  sum
If[#==0,{},{a=⌊++j#⌋,##&@@#0[j#-a]}]&@       j=1                   to factoriadic


JavaScript (Node.js), 93 bytes
f=([a=0,...A],[b=c=0,...B],i)=>k=A+B||a|b?f(A,B,i+1||2)!=-(b+=c+a,c=b>i,b+=c*~i)?[b,...k]:k:A

Try it online!
==- if former is [] and latter is 0. Former is never negative and latter, including -, is never positive

Setanta, 175 153 150 146 bytes
gniomh(x,y){z:=x+[0]*(fad@y-fad@x)le i idir(0,fad@y)z[i]+=y[i]le i idir(fad@z-1,0)ma i+1{z[i-1]+=z[i]//(i+2)z[i]%=i+2z[i]|scrios_cul@z()}toradh z}

try-setanta.ie link

JavaScript (Node.js), 166 bytes
(a,b)=>{b.map((x,i)=>a[i]=(a[i]?a[i]:0)+x);c=0;for(i=(y=a.length)-1;i>0;i--){d=(e=a[i]+c)%(z=i+2);c=e/z|0;a[i]=d};y?a[0]+=c:0;while(a[a.length-1]==0)a.pop();return a}

Try it online!
Expanded, with comments:

(a,b)=>{
b.map((x,i)=>a[i]=(a[i]?a[i]:0)+x); //add elements in arrays a and b, 
                                    //allowing for different size arrays.

c=0;                                //initialize carry

for(i=(y=a.length)-1;i>0;i--){      //adjust each value so it fits within the max
                                    //for that digit, 
                                    //carrying to the left as required.

d=(e=a[i]+c)%(z=i+2);               //use mod for the digit

c=e/z|0;                            //use divide and round for the carry

a[i]=d                              //put the digit back in the array

};

y?a[0]+=c:0;                        //add remaining carry to the first digit

while(a[a.length-1]==0)a.pop();     //remove trailing zeros

return a //return result

}


(a[i]?a[i]:0) could be (a[i]|0), and I think -1;i>0;i--) could be ;--i>0;). Also use ! instead of 0== (or if you used a newer version of Node on a different host you could use !a.at(-1)). And I don't think you need to use d, you could just set a[i] directly.
